# Probability of selecting a random dot in range $[0,1]$ is zero

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

How can I show that the probability of selecting a dot in range $[0,1]$ is zero?

Note : What I want is a formal proof. I know I should define some series that each of them has length between 0 and 1. But i don't know how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am going to assume that by random you mean uniformly at random. That means that no point is different from each other and they all have the same probability of being chosen. Then if the probability is $x > 0$ then you can pick $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x n > 1$.

That means that if you choose any $n$ points the probability of choosing any one of them is bigger than $1$ which is absurd.

Answer (score 1):

Let P stands for the searched probability P(T=x).
For any $\epsilon >0$

$P \leq P(T \in [x-\frac{\epsilon}{2},x+\frac{\epsilon}{2}]) \leq \epsilon$

So P being smaller that any positive real number, it is equal to 0.

Answer (score 0):

$T=\{a\}$ and $a\in [0,1]$. Using uniform distribution PDF
$$P(T)=\int_T dx=\int_a^a dx=0.$$